# Why did ThreadPoolExecutor work but ProcessPoolExecutor doesn't?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm learning about Threadings and Multiprocessing in Python 3. I tried a simple Programm which worked with ThreadPoolExecutor but when i changed to ProcessPoolExecutor it didn't do any of the code given..

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
import os

directory = r'C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Pictures\My Photos'
imgs_file = []


for img_file in os.listdir(directory):
    if (img_file.endswith(".JPG") or img_file.endswith(".jpg")):
        imgs_file.append(img_file)

def image_filter(image_file):
    img = Image.open(image_file)
    img= img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius = 9))
    img.save(f'Converted {image_file}')  

import concurrent.futures
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as p:
    p.map(image_filter, imgs_file)
```

Comment: What happens when you use a process pool? Note, you need to use a `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard if you are using multiprocessing

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the programm works when i put in the __main__ guard! Thanks a lot.